# my list variable array missing after click button

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I don't have DB, instead DB I have to list array, I have a table, and when I want Edit details of  Driver, I click 'edit', after that display change to page with details, after that I can change details and click save button, my problem that after clicking button 'save', my array list miss, I not very good in MVC, but I try my best! if somebody sees what I do wrong, please tell me and explain, thank you

that my controller

```
public class DriverTaxiController : Controller
{

    static  List<Drivers> Driver = new List<Drivers>();
    public static  int numLine = -1;

    // GET: DriverTaxi
    public ActionResult List()
    {

        Driver.Add(new Drivers() { Line = 1, NumberLicens = "123456", FirstName = "Evgeny", LastName = "Ryvkin", PhoneNumber = "0546819725", StartWork = "12/10/17", DateCheckEyes = "13/10/17"});
        Driver.Add(new Drivers() { Line = 2, NumberLicens = "123457", FirstName = "Moshe", LastName = "Kohen", PhoneNumber = "0546819725", StartWork = "12/10/17", DateCheckEyes = "13/10/17" });
        Driver.Add(new Drivers() { Line = 3, NumberLicens = "123458", FirstName = "Dana", LastName = "Multy", PhoneNumber = "0546819725", StartWork = "12/10/17", DateCheckEyes = "13/10/17" });

        ViewBag.Drivers = Driver;
        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult MyAction(int  id=0)
    {
       for(int i = 0; i < Driver.Count; i++)
        {

            if(Driver[i].Line == id)
            {
                ViewBag.nl = Driver[i].NumberLicens;
                ViewBag.fn = Driver[i].FirstName;
                ViewBag.ln = Driver[i].LastName;
                ViewBag.phone = Driver[i].PhoneNumber;
                ViewBag.start = Driver[i].StartWork;
                ViewBag.eye = Driver[i].DateCheckEyes;
                ViewBag.line = Driver[i].Line;
            }
        }

     numLine = id;

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update()
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        numLine--;
        Driver[numLine].NumberLicens = Request.Form["NumberLicens"];
        Driver[numLine].FirstName = Request.Form["FirstName"];
        Driver[numLine].LastName = Request.Form["LastName"];
        Driver[numLine].PhoneNumber = Request.Form["PhoneNumber"];
        Driver[numLine].StartWork = Request.Form["StartWork"];
        Driver[numLine].DateCheckEyes = Request.Form["DateCheckEyes"];

        return View("List2");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("MyAction");
    }

}
```

that my View Edit, when I click the button, my parameters not saved in my list, I don't understand why

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "DriverTaxi"))
     {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.NumberLicens, new { @Value = @ViewBag.nl }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.NumberLicens)
        <br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.FirstName, new { @Value = @ViewBag.fn })
        <br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.LastName, new { @Value = @ViewBag.ln })
        <br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.PhoneNumber, new { @Value = @ViewBag.phone })
        <br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.StartWork, new { @Value = @ViewBag.start })
        <br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.DateCheckEyes, new { @Value = @ViewBag.eye })
        <br />

        @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Line)

        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
    }
```

that my Table

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Number Licens</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Start Work</th>
            <th>Date Cheking the Eyes</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (Drivers p in ViewBag.Drivers)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@p.Line</td>
            <td>@p.NumberLicens</td>
            <td>@p.FirstName &nbsp; @p.LastName </td>
            <td>@p.PhoneNumber</td>
            <td>@p.StartWork</td>
            <td>@p.DateCheckEyes</td>



            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "MyAction", "DriverTaxi", new { id = p.Line }, null)
            </td>
            <td>addres</td>
            <td>email</td>
            <td><input id="Button2" type="submit" value="Delete" name="@p.NumberLicens" /></td>
        </tr>

    }`enter code here`
```

and that my error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC83j.png)

Comment: You have ActionResult List(), is that the action that renders your table?

Comment: yes, ActionResult List() render table.

Comment: But when you start your project, which controller action is the first one to execute?  Is that the "MyAction"?

Comment: execute index, but I do not use this page, and I write: http://localhost:49956/DriverTaxi/List
and open table

Comment: For every action that loads the table you need to make sure that Driver is loaded into ViewBag.Drivers, according to your error image there is a null reference error which means that perhaps some action has not assigned values to the ViewBag.Drivers

Comment: Understand, I check with Debugger, and after click button, just jump to this variable, I will check again! thank you

Comment: No problem.  Just make sure you assign your ViewBag in each of your actions, like "MyAction", "Update", etc.  You should only need to do this in each of them -->  ViewBag.Drivers = Driver;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add your ViewBag assignment to each of your actions that render view.  Something like this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(int  id=0)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < Driver.Count; i++)
    {

        if(Driver[i].Line == id)
        {
            ViewBag.nl = Driver[i].NumberLicens;
            ViewBag.fn = Driver[i].FirstName;
            ViewBag.ln = Driver[i].LastName;
            ViewBag.phone = Driver[i].PhoneNumber;
            ViewBag.start = Driver[i].StartWork;
            ViewBag.eye = Driver[i].DateCheckEyes;
            ViewBag.line = Driver[i].Line;
        }
    }

    numLine = id;
    ViewBag.Drivers = Driver; //TODO
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update()
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        numLine--;
        Driver[numLine].NumberLicens = Request.Form["NumberLicens"];
        Driver[numLine].FirstName = Request.Form["FirstName"];
        Driver[numLine].LastName = Request.Form["LastName"];
        Driver[numLine].PhoneNumber = Request.Form["PhoneNumber"];
        Driver[numLine].StartWork = Request.Form["StartWork"];
        Driver[numLine].DateCheckEyes = Request.Form["DateCheckEyes"];

        ViewBag.Drivers = Driver; //TODO

        return View("List2");
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Drivers = Driver; //TODO

        return View("MyAction");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, You just help me so much, because if I finish this little project, I will work in the company, so BIG THANK YOU!